# Include namespace for all classes in assembly in C#

Tags: c#

Is it possible to define an assembly-wide `using SomeNamespace` statement in C#, such that all classes and code files in that assembly include that namespace without having to specify `using SomeNamespace`?

Considering I can't find it in the MSDN documentation and haven't ran into it in the past 6 years of writing C#, I'm doubtful but figured I'd ask others anyway.

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: Resharper takes care of `using` for all my code. Don't even notice it anymore.

Comment: Namespaces are for disambiguating names, so what you want cannot be done automatically, it might lead to name clashes

Comment: that is not possible.unless you copy paste all decompiled code into one assemly and compile it again...

Comment: No. VB has project level `Imports`, the equivalent of C#s `using` directives. C# has no such concept at the project level.

Comment: not what you asked per se, but you could use `visual studio`'s built in `template` mechanics to generate templates that fit your need and always include the `using directives` that you want: http://malbrecht2.wordpress.com/2011/07/26/vs2010-itemtemplates/

Comment: [`Related`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21279869/in-csharp-can-we-collect-namespace-declarations-in-once-place#comment32065325_21279869), but answer is still no.

Comment: @JohnSaunders the use case is I have a namespace with extension methods that are used throughout that project. If you are familiar with using Visual Studio without Resharper then you know that you don't get intellisense for extension methods unless their namespace is already included, and you don't get the totally awesome Ctrl+. feature either. What I was looking for is a poor man's alternative to Resharper and manually typing out `using` statements when I need those extension methods. I'm certainly not opposed to `using` statements, it makes the code clear and highly copy-paste-able.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`using` doesn't exist in assemblies, or in the produced code.

It is a shorthand that only exists in the source code.

Consider the classic "Hello World":

```
using System;

namespace Hello
{
  class Program
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
  }
}
```

The actual bytecode of the `Main` method produced would be expressed as CIL assembly as:

```
ldstr "Hello World!"
call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
ret
```

Note that this is exactly the same as if we left the `using System` out of the C# source file, and used `System.Console.WriteLine()` instead. Indeed, it's even a bit more wordy than that, since the method signature used in the actual produced code includes the assembly as (`[mscorlib]`).

To speak of an "assembly-wide `using SomeNamespace`" is meaningless, as assemblies don't have any `using` at all.

Since `using` directives are something that is in a source file, rather than in an assembly, it's a source problem, not an assembly problem. Edit the templates your IDE uses to include those statements you need, or use one that adds `using` statements when it can only find matching intellisense suggestions by looking outside of the possible suggestions based on the current `using` directives for the file.

Comment: C# has two concepts that both use the `using` keyword. One is called a [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx), and the other is called a [`using` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx). Throughout your last paragraph, wherever you say `using` statement, you actually mean `using` directive.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for the catch. I was using `statement` in a general sense, but since that term has a specific sense here it was an inappropriate wording.